# Appcelerator Titanium - adding a MODULE

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have compiled an Android module for Titanium mobile SDK 2.1.3, but when I try to add it to an empty application I get the following error, when I try to build the app.

```
[ERROR] Error(s) compiling generated Java code
[ERROR] C:\Users\foobar\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\RT\build\android\gen\com\foobar\FBApplication.java:42: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class SpspmoduleBootstrap

location: package com.foobar.spspmodule

        runtime.addExternalModule("com.foobar.spspmodule", com.foobar.spspmodule.SpspmoduleBootstrap.class);
```

**Anyone have any ideas?**

Comment: Do you see `com.foobar.spspmodule` at your project root->modules->android ?

Comment: No, I thought that in the new module scheme, the zip file was to be placed at the root of the project.

Comment: after coping zip file at root, i generally connect my androind and "install to android device" so that zip file gets extracted to module-android folder